Python arrow_odbc issue with mysql odbc drivers libmyodbc9
I am losing my mind around this issue here. The problem started while I was using Polars to connect to both SqlServer and MySql databases through odbc drivers, which Polars handles making use of the arrow_odbc dependency. I reduced it to the bone to describe it here.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.12-slim AS build
# FROM --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.12-slim AS build

# install common dependencies
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y curl gnupg unixodbc unixodbc-dev wget

# install sqlserver odbc driver
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt update -y && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt install -y msodbcsql18

# install mysql odbc driver
ARG MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC=mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-linux-glibc2.28-x86-64bit
# ARG MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC=mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-linux-glibc2.28-aarch64

RUN wget -q https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/9.0/${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC}.tar.gz && \
    gunzip ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC}.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC}.tar && \
    cp -r ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC}/bin/* /usr/local/bin && \
    cp -r ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_ODBC}/lib/* /usr/local/lib && \
    myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc9w.so"

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install -U pip pdm
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

WORKDIR /app
COPY tasks/ingestion/[^task|Dockerfile]* ./
RUN pdm install --global --project .

COPY libraries/python/aws/ ./
COPY libraries/python/ingestion/ ./
COPY tasks/ingestion/task/ ./

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]

This is a script which does work:
import pyodbc

conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=host.docker.internal;DATABASE=<db>;UID=<id>;PWD=<pwd>;ENCRYPT=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
stmt = "select * from <table> limit 500"

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.execute(stmt)

This is a script which does NOT work:
import pyodbc
from arrow_odbc import read_arrow_batches_from_odbc

conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=host.docker.internal;DATABASE=<db>;UID=<id>;PWD=<pwd>;ENCRYPT=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
stmt = "select * from <table> limit 500"

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.execute(stmt)

reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(query=stmt, connection_string=conn_str)

This is a script which does NOT work either:
from arrow_odbc import read_arrow_batches_from_odbc

conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=host.docker.internal;DATABASE=<db>;UID=<id>;PWD=<pwd>;ENCRYPT=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
stmt = "select * from <table> limit 500"

reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(query=stmt, connection_string=conn_str)

And this is a script which does work again:
import pyodbc

conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=host.docker.internal;DATABASE=<db>;UID=<id>;PWD=<pwd>;ENCRYPT=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
stmt = "select * from <table> limit 500"

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.execute(stmt)

from arrow_odbc import read_arrow_batches_from_odbc

reader = read_arrow_batches_from_odbc(query=stmt, connection_string=conn_str)

The traceback I obtain in the first not working case is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/test_odbc_ko.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc9w.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

The traceback I obtain in the second not working case is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/test_odbc_ko.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/arrow_odbc/reader.py", line 495, in read_arrow_batches_from_odbc
    reader.query(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/arrow_odbc/reader.py", line 102, in query
    connection = connect_to_database(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/arrow_odbc/connect.py", line 59, in connect_to_database
    raise_on_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/arrow_odbc/error.py", line 30, in raise_on_error
    raise Error(error_out)
arrow_odbc.error.Error: ODBC emitted an error calling 'SQLDriverConnect':
State: 01000, Native error: 0, Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc9w.so' : file not found

As you can see from my examples, the problem here seems to be related to the underlying odbc engine initialization, which is performed by the pyodbc.connect(conn_str) command or by the from arrow_odbc import read_arrow_batches_from_odbc command based on which of the two is executed first.
I only included a MySql driver example because the SqlServer one does not cause any issue. To make things even more confusing, if I build the Docker image based on arm64 architecture (I included commented lines in the Dockerfile to switch between architectures and the relatively right mysql odbc driver version) everything works like a charm.
Please help me work this around and fix it for amd64 architecture. Thank you in advance.
UPDATE 1 (2024-08-02):
I tried different things:

Changed Dockerfile to use alpine and ubuntu as base images
Changed mysql connector installation method to deb distribution

Nothing changed.
